# Error con realizar ScrollToTop en react hooks

Tags: react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo un problema al querer que las pantallas se coloquen al inicio cuando navego en ellas,
quisiera que estén al inicio cada vez que cambio de pagina.

Mi codigo

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ScrollToTop({ children }) {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(pathname);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return children;
}
```

este es el metodo que utilizo para realizar como lo muestra esta documentacion  https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

Creo que el problema esta en el children que lo paso para que se muestre la pantalla.

MI app router esta de la siguiente manera

```
<>
      <AppContext.Provider value={initialState}>
      
        <BrowserRouter>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <Layout>
          
        
          <Switch>
          
            <Route  exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
        
            <Route exact path="/shop/:name/:banner" component={Shop}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/shop" component={Shop}></Route>

     
            <Route component={NotFound}></Route>

          </Switch>
          
         
      </Layout>
 <ScrollToTop/>

       
          
        </BrowserRouter>

      </AppContext.Provider>
      
    </>
```

tambien tengo mi componente  de layout donde uno todo

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="Main">
      <Header />
    
     {children}

      

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Porfa si alguien me puede ayudar ,

Comment: No entiendo, dónde está el `ScrollToTop` en tus componentes? Cómo lo usas?

Comment: @FranAcuna  lo utilizo dentro de BrowserRouter ne las rutas

Comment: Creo que lo agregaste mal, el cierre del `ScrollToTop` tiene que incluir el cierre de `Layout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución diferente al scrollTop que en mi caso no me funciono lo que hice fue en mi layout  colocar este codigo:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const scrollSpan= useRef();

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("scrolling");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

    const div = scrollSpan.current;
    div.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [handleScroll]);


  return (
    <div   ref={scrollSpan} className="Main scrollableContainer" >
       <Header />

        
            {children}

      <Footer />

       
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Hay que tomar mucho en cuenta la parte ref y agregar classname scrollableContainer que es necesario para que funcione aqui el css

```
.scrollableContainer {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;height: auto;
}
```

Con esto todas las paginas a las que me redirijo se colocan en la parte inicial , si deseas este mismo codigo se puede aplicar si necesitas que se redija a otra parte la pagina.Me imagino que no me funciono el scroolTop por la estructura que tenia de mis rutas y como esta formado la pagina . Espero que le sirva a alguien.